# Scala Generics, which of these 4 generic version is specific to which particular problem

Tags: scala, generics, higher-kinded-types

These four versions compile but i'm curious about context in which we should prefer one option rather than another.

```
// 1
def f[N, S <: Seq[N]](s: S)
// 2
def f[N, S[N] <: Seq[N]](s: S[N])
```

They are pretty similar when use `1` rather than `2`

`2` impose that `S` have `N` as generic parameter as `1` but then what is the difference between these two ?

Then we have more general settings.

```
// 3
def f[N, S[X] <: Seq[X]](s: S[N])
// 3.a
def f[N, S[X] <: Seq[X]](s: S[N]): S[Int]
```

From what i humbly understood `3` authorize to extract the generic container type to reuse it later and get something like `3.a`.

But what is the meaning of the undeclared X generic parameter, i suppose it's a way to declare something special but i don't get it.

```
// 4
def f[N, S[X] <: Seq[_]](s: S[N])
```

I don't know what to say about `4` except than from what i know `Seq[_]` stands for `Seq[Any]`

Finally i'm simply curious to have more information about these tools and their specificity to get things done more properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// 2
def f[N, S[N] <: Seq[N]](s: S[N])
```

The idea here is that the first `N` parameter and `N` mentioned in `S[N] <: Seq[N]` are completely independent parameters. They are just sharing the same name.

`N` mentioned in `S[N]` is visible only in a scope of its bound `<: Seq[N]`. 
`N` used in parameter definition `(s: S[N])` comes from first `N` as this is the only `N` parameter visible for parameter type definition. So instead of `N` in `S[N] <: Seq[N]` you can use any letter and this will not affect your parameter type at any way.

```
// 4
def f[N, S[X] <: Seq[_]](s: S[N])
```

<del>Here you just ignored `X` parameter.</del>

**Edit:** as @alexey-romanov mentioned in a comment. There is difference between `S[X] <: Seq[X]` and `S[X] <: Seq[_]`

Here is an example showing the difference:

```
def f1[N, S[X] <: Seq[X]](s: S[N]) = ""

def f2[N, S[X] <: Seq[_]](s: S[N]) = ""

type Foo[A] = Seq[Int]

val foo: Foo[String] = Seq(2,3)

//f1(foo) -- compilation error
f2(foo)
```

The problem here is as type constrictor is a kind of "function on types", we can define such "function" accepting one type as a parameter but returning type parametrized by another parameter not related to parameter  used in type constructor.  (See type `Foo`)

Passing `foo` val to `f2` is fine because `X` is infered to  String and `Foo[String]` is a "subtype"(actually they are equal) of `Seq[Int]`, but when we pass `foo` to `f1` the `X` is still a `String` but `Foo[String]` is not "subtype" of `Seq[String]` (because Foo[String]==Seq[Int] not subtype of Seq[String])

```
// 1
def f[N, S <: Seq[N]](s: S)
```

And here you said that `N` used in `Seq[N]` is the same as first parameter `N`. So this is the same `N`

Comment: Ok then, `2` and `3` are exactly the same, just a mather of naming, thanks !
But what's the difference between `3` and `4` ?

Comment: no difference. In both cased you are just saying that there can be any type instead of `X`. In 3 you used `X`  in `<: Seq[X]` without any extra restriction so this is the same as `_`

Comment: `def f[N, S[X] <: Seq[_]](s: S[N])`  is the same as  `def f[N, S[_] <: Seq[_]](s: S[N])`

Comment: Ok then if i have no need for restriction on `X`, `_` has more sense. But if desire to bound something insie `S` i will use `S[X <: Bound] <: Seq[X]` that's right ?
Thank you @Bogdan Vakulenko !

Comment: No, there is a difference between 3 and 4: E.g. if you declare `type Foo[A] = Seq[Int]`, it satisfies 4 but not 3.

Comment: Hmm...you are right.  It seems that `_` in this case means anything but there is no guaranty that this is `X` ... have no good explanation for this case and when it can be used if any.

Comment: @KyBe I've edited the answer to provide some explanation for this case as well.

Comment: The edited answer is still a bit incorrect: `_` isn't inferred to `Int`. `Seq[_]` is an existential type, and `Seq[Int]` is a subtype of `Seq[_]`.

Comment: @alexey-romanov thanks for your comment. should I read existential type `Seq[_]` as `Seq[Any]` when It appears in a bound position?

Comment: They are equivalent because of covariance.